# Fileupload inside repeater of updatepanel not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

To avoid auto post back I have used update panel covering my asp webpage which is having multiple repeater in it.
Each repeater having file upload control in it. Each file upload is showing me empty file when I am trying to save.

Answer (score 0):

File Upload control faces issues working with updatepanel

so to solve it

define a postback trigger for your control in the updatepanel,

or
if that doesn't work then use AsyncFileUpload control from Ajax toolkit